# Why does the datetime type in SQL Server Compact round values?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-ce, datetime2

I've run across something that surprised me.

I am using `WinPcap` to collect data off a network.  Internally, `WinPcap` uses the Windows performance counters to generate its timestamps.  I know they are subject to drift, but these timestamps nevertheless have precision down to the microsecond level.

If I insert these timestamps into a SQL Server Compact 4.0 database as a `datetime` value and extract them later, I noticed that the precision has dropped to milliseconds.

For example,

```
10:52:19.706084 -> 10:52:19.706000
```

Now, I have since read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) that SQL Server rounds values with the `datetime` type to .000, .003, or .007 milliseconds.  That explains what is happening.

Now, the `datetime` field uses 8 bytes to store its data, 4 bytes for the date and 4 for the milliseconds since midnight.  But if I call `DateTime.ToBinary()`, I get back an 8-byte number that represents the value in all of its precision.  In fact, if I write this value to the database in a `bigint` column and then call `DateTime.FromBinary()` when extracting that value, I get the original value with the same precision.

This is the approach I'm going to use, but I'm still curious:  Why didn't the original `datetime` type in SQL Server Compact use `DateTime`'s ToBinary/FromBinary storage mechanism?

**EDIT:**

As Aaron Bertrand rightly points out, SQL Compact does not support `datetime2`.  Further, `datetime2` uses 6, 7, or 8 bytes, not 54 bytes in regular SQL Server.  My basic question still stands, though.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729972/allow-entity-framework-4-5-to-use-datetime2-with-sql-server-ce4

Comment: Also I don't think Compact supports `datetime2`. And in "regular" SQL Server, it [certainly does not take 54 bytes (rather 6, 7 or 8 bytes)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx). Can you cite an official source for this `nvarchar(27)` bit?

Comment: Looking again, I think you're right on both counts.  Here's where I was looking but apparently not close enough...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Yeah that's the length of the string representation, not the storage size.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more precise in what I'm asking.  It's more of a curiosity that anything.  I was just surprised that inserting a timestamp into the database caused the value to lose data.  And I don't understand that when the `DateTime` struct can encode/decode itself in 8 bytes and maintain precision.

Comment: This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143259/what-is-the-internal-representation-of-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: I'm not sure why they chose the 4+4 storage mechanism for `datetime`, but at least they corrected it with `datetime2` (even if they chose a horrible name). Perhaps you could consider using SQL Server 2012 LocalDB instead of Compact, then you won't be limited by Compact's constant game of catch-up...

Comment: The accepted answer at the SO link you provided has a link to a pretty detailed writeup on the DATETIME type.  A quick glance makes me think the 4+4 format was chosen to aid queries based on time.  That at least seems plausible to me.  Can you provide a little more detail on the 'LocalDB' option?  Is it portable like Compact?

Comment: yes, the entire runtime is 33 MB. [I wrote up a lengthy article about it here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/) and the [official documentation starts here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the full internal details or the motivation behind the choice, but `datetime` is stored internally as - essentially - two 4-byte integers. One represents date, the other represents time. I suspect you lose some precision in the latter because of the way ticks / milliseconds have been handled since the very first versions of SQL Server, but again, I don't know low-level implementation details.

Related questions for more background info:

- [What is the internal representation of datetime in sql server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143259/what-is-the-internal-representation-of-datetime-in-sql-server)
- [Allow Entity Framework 4.5 to use datetime2 with SQL Server CE4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729972/allow-entity-framework-4-5-to-use-datetime2-with-sql-server-ce4)

In order to support the precision you want without moving the value in and out of binary format, I would suggest using [LocalDB](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5612/getting-started-with-sql-server-2017-express-localdb/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) which has the same portability advantages of Compact but without many of the feature limitations (such as support for the more precise `datetime2` type - which I assure you takes 6-8 bytes, not 54 :-)).